# Scala does not found implicit conversion

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, type-level-computation

I have written a wrapper around Map which:

- at the type level, keeps track of the keys which are present on the map;
- forces a correspondence between the key and value type.

This is the code:

```
package it.unich.jandom.utils.parametermap

import scala.annotation.implicitNotFound
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import TLists._

object PMaps2 {

  trait Parameter {
    type Value
    def ->(v: Value): (this.type, Value) = (this, v)
  }

  sealed class PMap(val delegate: Map[Parameter, Any]) {
    type PList <: TList

    @implicitNotFound("The parameter map has no element of type ${P}")
    def apply[P <: Parameter](p: P)(implicit ev: Contains[P, PList]) = delegate(p).asInstanceOf[P#Value]
    def get[P <: Parameter](p: P) = delegate.get(p).asInstanceOf[Option[P#Value]]
  }

  object PNil extends PMap(Map.empty[Parameter, Any]) {
    type PList = TNil
    // do not move this in the PMap trait!
    def ::[P <: Parameter](pkey: (P, P#Value)) = new PCons[P, PNil](pkey, this)
  }

  final class PCons[H <: Parameter, T <: PMap](pkey: (H, H#Value), other: T) extends PMap(other.delegate + pkey) {
    type PList = TCons[H,T#PList]
    // do not move this in the PMap trait!
    def ::[P <: Parameter](pkey: (P, P#Value)) = new PCons[P, H :: T](pkey, this)
  }

  type PNil = PNil.type
  type ::[P <: Parameter, T <: PMap] = PCons[P, T]

  implicit def conv[S <: PMap, T <: PMap](m: S)(implicit ev: SubSet[T#PList, S#PList]): T = m.asInstanceOf[T] 
}
```

TList is a type-level implementation of a list of type, similar to the one in [Metascala](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/metascala/wiki). Consider this example of use:

```
import it.unich.jandom.utils.parametermap.PMaps2._
object A extends Parameter { type Value = Int }
object B extends Parameter { type Value = String }
val y = (A -> 3) :: PNil     // has type A.type :: PNil
val x = (B -> "foo") :: y  // has type B.type :: A.type :: PNil
x(B)                         // returns "foo"
// y(B) does not compile
def f(x: A.type :: PNil) = {
  x(A)
}
f(y)   // returns 3
f(conv[B.type :: A.type :: PNil, A.type :: PNil](x))  // returns 3
// f(x) does not compile ------------ WHY?
```

The point is that `f(x)` does not compile, although `conv` is implicit and the the line immediately above works. Note that if I remove the implicit parameter `ev: SubSet[T#PList, S#PList]` from the definition of `conv`, then `f(x)` compiles.

I really cannot understand why this happens. Sorry for the long piece of code, but I am not able to replicate this problem with a sensibly shorter example.

Comment: Where is `SubSet` defined and what is its semantics?